'ReactNativeMoEngage/MoEngageReactUtils.h' file not found
not sure what i did wrong here, but i'm trying to integrate MoEngage into our project using React Native.
Android Works fine, integration, notification push, inapp etc all works fine.
but now we try to integrate the iOS part of it, but for some reason we hit the same error everytime
MoEReactNativeInboxHandler.m:10:9 'ReactNativeMoEngage/MoEngageReactUtils.h' file not found
we, of course, already run the pod install, and it works just fine, not error thrown, but it seems the error is still persist
any advice ?
thank you in advance
